# The view function did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement

Tags: arrays, numpy, flask

I try return the result of function np.correlate, using flask and numpy

```
  from flask import Flask
import numpy as np
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/")
def corelation():
    # 1 2 3 8 9 7 3 12 65 45 26 33
     firstArray = np.loadtxt("C:\\Users\\user\\source\\repos\\CorelationApplication\\firstfile.txt")
    # 43 32 23 45 65 99 77 11 20 32 65 11 12
     secondArray = np.loadtxt("C:\\Users\\user\\source\\repos\\CorelationApplication\\secondfile.txt")
     corr = np.correlate(firstArray,secondArray, 'full')  
     result = print (corr)  
     # 1.2000e+01 3.5000e+01 1.2300e+02 2.9100e+02 4.7500e+02 8.5000e+02
     # 1.2000e+01 3.5000e+01 1.2300e+02 2.9100e+02 4.7500e+02 8.5000e+02
     # 1.2000e+01 3.5000e+01 1.2300e+02 2.9100e+02 4.7500e+02 8.5000e+02
     # 1.2000e+01 3.5000e+01 1.2300e+02 2.9100e+02 4.7500e+02 8.5000e+02
     return result
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug = True)
```

I getting this message:The view function did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement

Comment: `print(corr)` is returning None, hence this view function is returning None. What result are you trying for here?

Comment: I want to get a list of all the values from an array
[1.2000e+01 3.5000e+01 1.2300e+02 2.9100e+02 4.7500e+02 8.5000e+02
 1.1130e+03 1.3660e+03 2.0930e+03 3.4580e+03 7.3460e+03 8.1230e+03
 6.9700e+03 7.0390e+03 9.3660e+03 1.2554e+04 1.2265e+04 1.1638e+04
 8.9900e+03 6.9460e+03 6.3180e+03 3.5260e+03 2.1740e+03 1.4190e+03]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you need is a textual representation of an np.array, the simplest way to get there is

```
from flask import make_response

...
corr = np.correlate(firstArray,secondArray, 'full')
response = make_response(str(corr), 200)
response.mimetype = 'text/plain'
return response
```

Comment: thank you very much! This is what I needed